# Force user to fill all fields before enabling form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form containing various fields.

See [**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2rje245/).

My aim is to enable the submit button only when the user has filled in all fields.

So far, I'm able to force the title field to have content before submit button is enabled. How do I make it so that all other fields need to be filled too **before** submit button is enabled.

```js
    jQuery("input[type='text']").on("keyup", function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() != "" ) {
            if (jQuery("#titlenewtide").val() != '')
            {
                jQuery("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        } else {
            jQuery("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="new_tide">
        Title: <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required> <br>
        Description: <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea> <br>
        Tag:  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required> <br>
        Category: <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required> Animation
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button> 
    </form>
```

Note that I am loading the JavaScripts in my footer.

Comment: I will bounty this question with 100 points when eligible in hopes for a solution that will work in all browsers.

Comment: Be glad, I have hopefully a very nice solution to upload soon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- ***Make the changes take effect after changing inputs values:***

On each `input` change, test the values of other `inputs` and checked state of `radio`, if all `inputs` has been entered it will make the submit `button` enabled:

```
var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
  var validForm = true;
  inputs.each(function(index) {
    var input = $(this);
    if (!input.val() || (input.type === "radio" && !input.is(':checked'))) {
      $("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      validForm = false;
    }
  });
  return validForm;
}

inputs.change(function() {
  if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
    $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var inputs = $("form#myForm input, form#myForm textarea");

var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
  var validForm = true;
  inputs.each(function(index) {
    var input = $(this);
    if (!input.val() || (input.type === "radio" && !input.is(':checked'))) {
      $("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      validForm = false;
    }
  });
  return validForm;
}


inputs.change(function() {
  if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
    $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">

  Title:
  <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required>
  <br>Description:
  <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  <br>Tag:
  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required>
  <br>Category:
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required>Animation
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Also it uses the form `id="myForm"`, so you can use it to validate only specific forms in your pages.

*Note: This is tested and working on `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `IE`.*

---

### EDIT:

- ***Make the changes take effect when we type in the inputs:***

In the previous code we are using `onchange` event handler to call the function so it's only called when we click outside a given input (after change).

To perform the call automatically when the user enters a character in a field (the last one) we need to use the `onkeyup` event so we don't need to click outside of it.

This is the changed code you need :

```js
    var inputs = $("form#myForm input, form#myForm textarea");

    var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
      var validForm = true;
      inputs.each(function(index) {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!input.val() || (input.type === "radio" && !input.is(':checked'))) {
          $("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
          validForm = false;
        }
      });
      return validForm;
    }


    inputs.each(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.type === "radio") {
        input.change(function() {
          if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
            $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      } else {
        input.keyup(function() {
          if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
            $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">

  Title:
  <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required>
  <br>Description:
  <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  <br>Tag:
  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required>
  <br>Category:
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required>Animation
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: When clicking inside an input, and then clicking outside of it, it will enable the submit button...?

Comment: no need to iterate `inputs` using `each` to apply change handler ... `inputs.change()` is same thing

Comment: @HenrikPetterson yes but only if all the inputs was entered/checked.

Comment: No, I just tested this on latest version of FF and was able to enable the submit button even when there are no content inside the fields.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I just edited it, and I tested it with FF and IE and it works perfectly

Comment: Thank you for the update. I can't seem to make this work correctly. Note that I am loading the JS code in my footer. Is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: If you enter something in every field the button enables, then if you remove content from any field it remains enabled. OP didnt specify this behaviour, but its pretty common.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you for pointing it out, I fixed it, we only need to reset the button to disabled by adding this line `$("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");` before returning `false`.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I don't think so but it may be that, try to includ ethe script in the head of the page and test it, because anyway the function call should be atached to the change event of the inputs once the page is loaded.

Comment: @chsdk I ran final tests with this code and everything is working beside one major issue. In FF and likely all browsers, the submit button is enable only once the user clicks outside of the textarea. To test this, click the radio button first, then fill all the input/textarea... one you are at the last one, the submit button doesn't get enabled until you click outside of it, which is highly confusing for the user. Do you have a fix for this? Thanks for the code regardless, I learned a lot!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yes of course we can do it we should just use the `onkeyup` event instead of the `onchange` event to perform the change instantly when the users enters some characters, take a look at my EDIT you will find what you need.

Answer (score 10):

Use this code below. On each input, it will check all the form fields by using this function `validate()`.

```
jQuery("input[type='text'], textarea").on("input", function () {
    var isValid = validate();
    if (isValid) {
      jQuery("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        jQuery("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});


function validate() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('input, textarea').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '')
        isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2rje245/2/)

**Update**

To make it validate if the form has `id="new_tide"` and fix about the `radio` button.

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea").on("change input", function() {
  validate($(this));
});

$("input:radio[name='category']").on("change", function() {
    validate($(this));
});

function validate(self) {
  if (self.parents("form:first").attr("id") == "new_tide") {
    var isValid = true;
    $('input[type="text"], textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '')
        isValid = false;
    });

    if (!$("input:radio[name='category']").is(':checked'))
      isValid = false;

    if (isValid) {
      $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2rje245/6/)

Comment: This is very nice. Although 2 adjustments. Can i make it only target if form has id="new_tide" and currently the submit button is enabled prior to the radio button (category) being selected...?

Comment: note that `input` event is not available in older browsers and some have quirks when removing characters

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I have update the code to target if the form has `id` "new_tide"

Comment: Can be shortened and optimized to just `function validate(){ $('input, textarea').each(function(){ if ($(this).val() === '') return false }); return true }`

Comment: @charlietfl Updated, I added `change, input` so it should work now on older browser.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan Did you make the final updates to the fiddle as well? Also, did you implement DJDavid98's suggestion? I will definitely bounty this one 100 points when eligible, this has saved me a lot of work.

Comment: events are space separated not comma delimited in `on()`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yeah updated, there's another answer other than mine maybe you can check that also.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan Thank you very much. Allow me to perform a few tests before I accept it as correct.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan I just started a 100 point bounty on this. I have added this in my test environment and it doesn't seem to work correctly. Note that I am loading the JS code at the very footer of the page, is that a problem in this case?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Are you adding those input fields dynamically? Also are you getting any errors on your console tab? No I don't think putting JS code at the footer will cause a problem as long as it's before the ending `</body>` tag.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you need to wrap it into jQuery(document).ready(function () {}...?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yes, if you haven't wrap that yet.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you can do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $inputs = $("#new_tide input:not([type=hidden]), #new_tide textarea");

    $inputs.on("input change", function () {
        valid = true;
        $inputs.each(function () {
            valid *= this.type == "radio" ? this.checked : this.value != "";
            return valid;
        });    
        $("#subnewtide").prop("disabled", !valid);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="new_tide">
    Title: <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required> <br>
    Description: <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea> <br>
    Tag:  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required> <br>
    Category: <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required> Animation
    Hidden: <input type="hidden">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: For clarification, will this work if I have <input type="hidden" somewhere within the form? That field may remain empty...

Comment: I believe the solution would be to add input[type='text'] instead

Comment: So far, everything seems to work on my test environment besides the radio button part of the code. The submit button is enabled before the radio button is ticked. Do you know why?

Comment: Oddly enough, this seems to be the only code that works on my site. Although the submit button is enabled **before** the radio button is clicks. Do you know why?

Answer (score 5):

Try utilizing `.siblings()` , `.map()` to compile values of `form` elements , `Array.prototype.every()` to return `Boolean` representation of `input` , `textarea` values , set `disabled` property of `form input[type=submit]` element

```js
$("form *[required]").on("input change", function(e) {
  $(this).siblings("[type=submit]").prop("disabled"
  , !$(this).siblings(":not([type=submit])").add(this).map(function(_, el) {
    return el.type === "radio" ? el.checked : el.value
   }).get().every(Boolean)
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="new_tide">
    Title: <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required> <br>
    Description: <textarea name="description" id="description" required></textarea> <br>
    Tag:  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required> <br>
    Category: <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required> Animation
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest, would be to rely on the HTML5 validation you're already using.

You'd have to add `required` to all form controls if you want to require all of them, and that can easily be done by using jQuery's [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector and setting the property, like so

```
$(':input:not(#subnewtide)').prop('required', true)
```

We'll exclude the  submit button, as that doesn't have to be required, obviously, not that it would matter in this case.

Then we'll listen for the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, which covers all sorts of inputs, like typing, pasting etc, and the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event as well to cover the radio button.

Using `form.checkValidity()` tells us if the form is valid, and returns a boolean, so we could use it directly to set the `disabled` property of the submit button.

All together it looks like this, and that's all you need, a few lines of really simple code

```
$(':input:not(#subnewtide)').prop('required', true).on('input change', function() {
    $('#subnewtide').prop( 'disabled', !this.form.checkValidity() );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2rje245/11/)

If you have to support old browsers that don't have HTML5 validation, you can use the [H5F polyfill](https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is base on standard JavaScript.

**HTML form**

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="new_tide" name="form1">
    Title: <input onkeyup="myBtnActivator(1)" id="titlenewtide" name="title" type="text" required> <br>
    Description: <textarea onkeyup="myBtnActivator(2)" id="description" name="description"></textarea> <br>
    Tag: <input id="newtag" onkeyup="myBtnActivator(3)" name="newtag" type="text" required> <br>
    Category: <input name="category" onchange="myBtnActivator(4)" type="radio" value="19" required> Animation
    <button id="subnewtide" name="subnewtide" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("subnewtide").disabled = true;
    var input1 = false;
    var input2 = false;
    var input3 = false;
    var input4 = false;

    function myBtnActivator(i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                input1 = true;
                if (document.form1.title.value == "")
                    input1 = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                input2 = true;
                if (document.form1.description.value == "")
                    input2 = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                input3 = true;
                if (document.form1.newtag.value == "")
                    input3 = false;
                break;
            case 4:
                input4 = true;
                if (document.form1.subnewtide.value == "")
                    input4 = false;
                break;
        }
        trigger();
    }

    function trigger() {
        if (input1 == true && input2 == true && input3 == true && input4 == true) {
            document.getElementById("subnewtide").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("subnewtide").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jquery validate . It's a good plugin .

The logic works like, any change in the form it will check the form is valid or not. And also using the errorplacement function it will disable the default error message also.

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#contactForm").validate({
        rules: {
            title: "required",
            description: {
                required: true
            },
            newtag: {
                required: true
            },
            category: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return true;
        },
        submitHandler: function() {


        }
    });


    $('#contactForm').change(function() {
        if ($("#contactForm").valid()) {
            $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4hLv2au/)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a pretty easy approach. I'm using native JavaScript, but I think it is applicable in jQuery as well:

```
var form = document.getElementById("new_tide");
form.onchange = function onChange() {
    var enable = true;
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var textareas = form.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

    for (var i in inputs) {
        enable = enable && inputs[i].value != "";
    }

    for (var i in textareas) {
        enable = enable && textareas[i].value != "";
    }

    enable = enable && textarea.value != "";
    document.getElementById("subnewtide").disabled = !enable;
}
```

The change event on form is always called, when any input or textarea element was changed (click in element, type, click somewhere else or lose focus).

**Edit:**
Regarding hidden fields, you can exclude them by surrounding the enable calculation with an if-condition:

```
if (!inputs[i].hidden) {
    enable = enable && inputs[i].value != "";
}
```

**Note:**
This will work in any browser (even Internet Explorer 5.5). Check on MDN:

[for ..in Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Browser_compatibility)
[element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName#Browser_compatibility)
[document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, although it doesn't seem to work. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ujuL5waw/

Answer (score 1):

Thought I might chip in. Assuming as little as possible.

```
jQuery("input, textarea").on("keyup click", function () { // going vanilla after easy-mode attach
    var sub = document.getElementById('subnewtide');
    if (require_all(find_form(this))) {
        sub.removeAttribute('disabled');
        sub.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sub.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        sub.disabled = true;
    }
});

function concat(a, b) { // concating Array-likes produces Array
    var slice = [].slice; // not assuming Array.prototype access
    return [].concat.call(
        slice.call(a, 0),
        slice.call(b, 0)
    );
}

function find_form(e) { // shim input.form
    if (e) do {
        if (e.tagName === 'FORM') return e;
    } while (e = e.parentNode);
    return null;
}

function require_all(form, dontIgnoreHidden) { // looks at textareas & inputs (excluding buttons)
    var inp = concat(form.getElementsByTagName('input'), form.getElementsByTagName('textarea')),
        rad = {}, // not assuming Object.create
        i, j,
        has = {}.hasOwnProperty; // not assuming Object.prototype access
    for (i = 0; i < inp.length; ++i) {
        switch ((inp[i].type || '').toLowerCase()) {
            default: // treat unknown like texts
            case 'text':
                if (!inp[i].value) return false; break;
            case 'checkbox':
                if (!inp[i].checked) return false; break;
            case 'radio':
                j = inp[i].getAttribute('name');
                if (!rad[j]) rad[j] = inp[i].checked;
                break;
            case 'hidden':
                if (dontIgnoreHidden && !inp[i].value) return false; break;
            case 'button':
            case 'submit':
                break;
        }
    }
    for (j in rad) if (!has || has.call(rad, j)) // not assuming hasOwnProperty
        if (!rad[j]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to accomplish that. It involves attaching a `change` event listener to `:radio` and `:checkbox` elements and an `input` event listener to other elements. These can both use a common predefined `handler` that will count the number of `unfilled` element each time each of these events fires on the appropriate element.

```js
function checkForm() {
    //define and initialize variables
    var unfilled = 0,
        form = $(this.form);

    //disable submit button if enabled
    $(':submit', form).prop('disabled', true);

    //count number of unfilled elements
    $(':input', form).each(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':radio,:checkbox') ) {
            $('input[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').length || unfilled++;
        } else {
            $('[name=' + this.name + ']').val() || unfilled++;
        }
    });
  
    //enable submit button if no unfilled element is found
    unfilled || $(':submit', form).prop('disabled', false);
}

//set up event listeners to fire above handler
$(':text,textarea,select').on('input', checkForm);
$(':radio,:checkbox').on('change', checkForm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="new_tide">
    Title: <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required> <br>
    Description: <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea> <br>
    Tag:  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required> <br>
    Category: <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required> Animation
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var inputs = $("form#myForm input, form#myForm textarea");

    var validateInputs = function validateInputs(inputs) {
      var validForm = true;
      inputs.each(function(index) {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!input.val() || (input.type === "radio" && !input.is(':checked'))) {
          $("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
          validForm = false;
        }
      });
      return validForm;
    }


    inputs.each(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.type === "radio") {
        input.change(function() {
          if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
            $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      } else {
        input.keyup(function() {
          if (validateInputs(inputs)) {
            $("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">

  Title:
  <input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required>
  <br>Description:
  <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  <br>Tag:
  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required>
  <br>Category:
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="19" required>Animation
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining your code instead of code dumping?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this html<br>
HTML:
<br>
<pre>
<form action="#" method="post" id="">
        Title: ##<input id="titlenewtide" type="text" name="title" required> 
        Description: <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
        Tag:  <input id="newtag" type="text" name="newtag" required> 
        Category: <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" name="category" id="cate"value="19" required > Animation
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtide" id="subnewtide" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

</form>
</pre>
validation code:<br>
//on each key up function intiate the function validate
<pre>
    jQuery("input[type='text']").on("keyup", function () {
        validate();
    });
    jQuery("#description").on("keyup", function () {
        validate();
    });

    function validate(){
     jQuery("input[type='text']").each(function(){

        if (jQuery(this).val() != "" )
        {
            if((jQuery("#description").val() !="") && (jQuery("#cate").is(':checked')))
            {

                jQuery("#subnewtide").removeAttr("disabled"); 
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#subnewtide").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        } 
    });
    }
    </pre>
    you can find the fiddle in : https://jsfiddle.net/s8uv2gkp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maytham Fahmi's relatively easy solution can be made even easier by passing `this.name`.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="new_tide" name="form1">
    <input onkeyup="myBtnActivator(this.name)" name="title" type="text" required> <br>
    <textarea onkeyup="myBtnActivator(this.name)" name="description"></textarea> <br>
    <input id="newtag" onkeyup="myBtnActivator(this.name)" name="newtag" type="text" required> <br>
    <input name="category" onchange="myBtnActivator(this.name)" type="radio" value="19" required> Animation
    <button id="subnewtide" name="subnewtide" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`this` refers to the DOM object that called the function. So the switch can just directly take the name, or the value, or anything else you can pass with DOM.

```
myBtnActivator(n)
{
    switch(n)
    {
        case "title":
            break;
        case "description":
            break;
        case "newtag":
            break;
        case "category":
            break;
    }
}
```