# Make Download Link not Trigger beforeunload

Tags: javascript, html, download, anchor, onbeforeunload

I have an application where the user enters a good deal of information.  Accordingly, it is important to use the `beforeunload` event so that the user doesn't accidentally leave the page and lose their progress. However, the app also requires download links and the problem is that clicking those download links triggers the beforeunload event even though the download does *not* cause the user to leave the page.

How can I set this up so that the the user has to confirm before leaving the page but that this confirmation is *not* triggered by clicking a download link?

You can see the whole thing in a reproducible example here:

- Live page: https://wqy9kn5qv7.codesandbox.io/
- Source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/wqy9kn5qv7

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a hack, but I think it will prevent the `beforeunload` event from firing on your download links:

```
<a href="somefile.txt" download target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Basically, add the `download` attribute to the element and a `target` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this does it! Though it does have some negative side effects (safari treats it as a pop-up and tries to block it).  Any way to avoid that?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `required` attribute at `<input>` and/or `<textarea>` elements to prevent `<form>` submission until the `required` fields have been completed.

See

- [Force user to fill all fields before enabling form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762447/force-user-to-fill-all-fields-before-enabling-form-submit)

also

- [Local store for form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533107/local-store-for-form-data)